# How to get Neo4j webadmin console to properly work with copy and paste?

Tags: google-chrome, neo4j, user-experience

I want to dump some of my entities using webadmin console like this:

```
dump match (n:Country) return n;
```

But there are two problems with this. First: the output has leading arrows `==>` which get selected along with the rest of the text:

```
==> begin
==> create constraint on (n:`Country`) assert n.`code` is unique
==> create (_3923:`Country` {`alt_name`:"Malta", `code`:"MT"})
==> create (_3924:`Country` {`alt_name`:"Germany", `code`:"DE")
==> create (_3925:`Country` {`alt_name`:"France", `code`:"FR"})
==> create (_3926:`Country` {`alt_name`:"Italy", `code`:"IT"})
==> create (_3927:`Country` {`alt_name`:"Spain", `code`:"ES"})
==> create (_3928:`Country` {`alt_name`:"Poland", `code`:"PL")
==> create (_3929:`Country` {`alt_name`:"Belgium", `code`:"BE"})
==> create (_3930:`Country` {`alt_name`:"Sweden", `code`:"SE"})
==> create (_3931:`Country` {`alt_name`:"Austria", `code`:"AT"})
==> create (_3932:`Country` {`alt_name`:"Greece", `code`:"GR"})
==> create (_3933:`Country` {`alt_name`:"Ireland", `code`:"IE"})
==> ;
==> commit
```

And secondly the text selection disappear as soon as I release mouse button (this one is an issue only in Chrome - when I use Firefox the selection behaves normally).

I know that I can use the system shell to connect to Neo4j shell, and those problems are gone. But I don't always have access to the server's shell and setting up a connection directly to Neo4j shell is a waste of time since I have the console already open in the browser.

First question: is there a way to configure the Webadmin console in such way that it would not display the leading arrows? Second: how to make selection behave properly in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with your second question, at least on a Mac with a mouse. (I don't know if this works on Windows.) If this works for you, then your first question should be moot, since you can just copy and edit the dump result.

- Use the left mouse button to select the lines you want.
- Keeping the left mouse button depressed, click the right mouse button.
- The popup context menu displays, and "Copy" should be an option.
- You should be able to release both mouse buttons, without losing the selection or the context menu.
- Click on the "Copy" option to copy the selection to the clipboard. (The context menu goes away but the selection now remains!)
- Paste from the clipboard to your favorite editor.